# ScyllaDB - DynamoDB Migration

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database-migration, dbmigrate, scylla, dynamo-local

Agenda- **Migrate DynamoDB tables to ScyllaDB** (Schema as well as data)

Does the Scylla-Migrator - https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-migrator can migrate the table schema as well, or  I have to create the exact schema in my ScyllaDB and then it can just migrate the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create the keyspace and table in remote cluster,
migrator can map old table to new table layout if needed.

The reason why we don't migrate schema automagically is that most of times you want to have it different (e.g. different compactions strategy, or new columns)
and then having this as manual step makes sure you can review your schema before using it.

That said I think it makes sense to ask for a special flag that will just migrate old schema for you to new cluster - https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-migrator/issues - can you file it there?

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, One follow-up question -
Is there a way to migrate multiple tables at once? Or we can only migrate one table at a time from source to target. @Lubos

Comment: @AradhanaSingh unfortunately right now it's one config and one job per table
reason is that some tables (e.g. with collections) cannot run with preserve timestamps on, so we want to make sure people understand the implications and run manually, after all it's all about data.